# To delete "Test" from view column

Tags: mysql

I want to delete column from database view, here, I want to delete `Test` column but it couldn't work when I try through SQL queries:

[image]

Comment: Are you deleting a column or a view? You have to make up your mind here. That screenshot is also virtually useless. Can you describe your schema with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` or something plain-text you can paste into your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use This...

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name" DROP COLUMN "Test";
```